# specifying java -D options for grails application

Tags: java, grails, logging

I am trying to specify java.util.logging.config.file when running a grails app and it doesn't seem to be working.
Here's what I'm trying:

```
export GRAILS_OPTS="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties"
export JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties"
grails -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties run-job myJob
```

In the beginning I see verbose messages but once grails forks job processor somehow both command line and env options are lost.

Answer (score 1):

Grails is using Gradle behind the scenes. Gradle is invoking separate VM to run or test application by default and this VM does not have those properties set. What you can do is, you can modify your `build.gradle` file to pass system properties from Gradle VM to forked VM. Something like this works for us:

```
bootRun { 
    systemProperty 'server.port', System.getProperty('server.port')
}
```

It is also possible to pass all properties using `System.getProperties()`. There is a lot of examples on this if you use Google. Check something like: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-should-i-be-handling-passing-system-properties-from-gradle-to-my-tests/7171

Also, you are using relative path to your `logging.properties` file, in some situations current path may be different and using absolute path may be better for verification.

Comment: Well problem with passing this particular property manually is that you have to then re-initialize the logging system.  Plus I was hoping to make this happen without having to modify a code and releasing new build to production.  It is not clear to me why forking doesn't preserve environment variables.

Comment: What do you mean by "passing manually", "reinitialize logging" and "modify the code for release"? You shouldn't have such issues. In `build.gradle` you can use it just for development, in production you can use standard properties set for application container. Gradle is very flexible here in my opinion

Comment: Passing manually -- I mean setting the java property manually, like System.setProperty().  But that doesn't do anything because at the point logging is initialized.  I am not sure how grade plays into it and what you mean by standard properties for app container.   Also there is no app container, this is not running in an app container.

Comment: How do you run the app in production then?

Comment: I wrote in the question -- grails run-job myJob.  Is that wrong?  I have no idea how grails apps are packaged for production (and I have no idea why this is a grails app to begin with)

Comment: With most Grails apps, you will package the app to ".war" (web archive file) and deploy it on application server like Apache Tomcat, Jetty, etc. Then you configure environment for this container not for app. But if you really use grails to run production instance (not recommended), you can use my answer, because it sets system property from command line parameter. If you use `grails -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties run-job myJob` and add `bootRun {...}` part of answer, replacing `server.port` with `java.util.logging.config.file` it should work

Comment: If this is not clear `systemProperty 'java.util.logging.config.file', System.getProperty('java.util.logging.config.file')` sets value of `java.util.logging.config.file` system property to value returned by `System.getProperty('java.util.logging.config.file')` function, which returns `logging.properties` if you call `grails -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties run-job myJob`